# Change Integrated Terminal title in vscode

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

We can open command prompt in vscode by using the `Integrated Terminal` feature in `View` menu.

We can even open multiple terminals as shown below:

[image: Integrated terminal]
Is there any way I can change the title of the terminal ?

- **1: cmd.exe** will be **build terminal**
- **2: cmd.exe** will be **watch terminal**

I have gone through the [integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) documentation but I didn't find a way to do that.

Comment: I'm interested in the same thing, I'de like to be able to change the title so I know the hostname of machine I've ssh'd to

Comment: Sadly microsoft closed and locked the feature request at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63264 and now we need an extension for auto-renaming terminal windows, as manual renaming is close to useless for practical use.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Press in windows **Ctrl + Shift + P** and after type: Terminal: Rename, there you can **change the terminal name/title**

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: for Mac, it's cmd + shift + p

Answer (score 12):

In v1.61 there is the ability to set the terminal names using variables.  See [terminal custom titles in release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_61.md#custom-title-and-description).

> Terminal names are traditonally the name of the process they're
> associated with. Thus, it can be difficult to distinguish between
> them.
>
> We now support configuring both title and description to help with
> this using variables described in `terminal.integrated.tabs.title` and
> `terminal.integrated.tabs.description` settings.
>
> The current default values are:

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.tabs.title": "${process}",
  "terminal.integrated.tabs.description": "${task}${separator}${local}${separator}${cwdFolder}"
}
```

Variables available are:

```
${cwd} - The terminal's current working directory  
${cwdFolder} - The terminal's current working directory.  
${workspaceFolder} - The workspace in which the terminal was launched.  
${local} - Indicates a local terminal in a remote workspace.  
${process} - The name of the terminal process.  
${separator} - A conditional separator (" - ") that only shows when surrounded by variables with values or static text.  
${sequence} - The name provided to xterm.js by the process.  
${task} - Indicates this terminal is associated with a task.
```

It looks like the `${task}` variable is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, plugins will remove default keyboard shortcut bindings.

Look for "terminal.rename" in keyboard shortcuts then edit the keyboard shortcut to your preferred shortcut.

[image]

To apply your shortcut, make sure your cursor is focus in edit part of the window before you key in. Not at the terminal part.

Answer (score 1):

In v1.41 there is a new command which can be used like so:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+t",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.renameWithArg",
  "args": {
      "name": "remote"
  }
}
```

if you have some frequently used name, like "remote" or "build" that you use often.

Answer (score 0):

With VSCode 1.63 (Nov. 2021), entering "`<blank>`" (ie., empty string) as name will restore the default name for that terminal.

See [issue 134020](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134020)

For instance:

> If my setting is `${cwd}${separator}${process}` and I name a terminal "`foo`".
> How do I reset "`foo`" back to the value of `${cwd}${separator}${process}`?
> My suggestion was that if you attempted to submit a blank name that would automatically reset to the value of your setting.