# How to show integrated terminals in VS Code as tabs rather then dropdown, how to rename them?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am wandering to find the way to show integrated terminals in VS Code as tabs rather then dropdown, and give them names. Its a habit that come from WebStrom as on pic 1. Is it possible to do so? Now it looks like on pic 2, and there is no way to rename tabs which is also desirable.

pic 1
[image: WebStorm way to show terminals]

pic 2
[image: VS Code way to show terminals]

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898299/change-integrated-terminal-title-in-vscode/59222628#59222628 for an update on renaming teminal tabs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code Integrated Terminal Tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406096/vs-code-integrated-terminal-tabs)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67309079/836330 with demo. Terminal Tabs will be in v1.56 next week.

Answer (score 3):

Showing it as tabs is not possible currently according to [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10546). However, you can use an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.terminal-tabs) which shows terminal tabs at the bottom.

Inorder to rename a terminal,

Open the command palette by clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and type "Terminal:Rename"

[image: Terminal:Rename]

Click <kbd>Enter</kbd> you will get:

[image]

Enter the name you need and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>