# Change Integrated Terminal title in vscode through Powershell script

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using VScode for running my same powershell script with different parameters in different powershell.

Is there any way I can name the terminal title through powershell script so that I can differentiate for what parameters I've run in which terminal ?

Instead of `1:PowerShell` and `2:PowerShell` I need `alpha` and `beta` from parameteres of powershell,
I've checked this answer [Change Integrated Terminal title in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898299/change-integrated-terminal-title-in-vscode), but it requires manual intervention.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The numbers will remain but you can change the title by first opening command palette (`Ctrl + Shift + P`) and then search for `Terminal: Rename`.
Then you can type whatever name you want to give.