# VSCode Terminal not showing names

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to have VSCode show me the folder/project name next to zsh, but recently it just stopped showing up. I have no idea what I did. Any ideas what config to change? This coincided with me changing the zsh prompt, but I changed it back and it's still not showing.

[image]

Comment: You set these yourself - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69430613/836330 for example.